# Как создать таблицу в Oracle, если её еще нет?

Tags: oracle, java, sql

Если выполнить запрос "`CREATE TABLE some_name`", то jdbc выбросит исключение

> `ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object`

при условии наличия в базе таблицы с именем `some_name`. Можно перехватить конкретно это исключение.

```
try {
    if (stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE scn_test (value NUMBER)")) {
        System.out.println("Table scn_test is successfully created.");
    }
} catch (SQLSyntaxErrorException e) {
    if (e.getErrorCode() != 955) { 
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Правильно ли это? Есть ли более верный подход?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_name

Comment: Это не работает в Oracle:

>`ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`

Comment: @javax, а чем Вас exception смущает ?

Comment: @javax не может быть, чтобы Oracle не поддерживал предикат "IF NOT EXISTS" - это стандартный SQL

Comment: Как-то странно использовать внешний по отношению к базе данных инструмент.

Comment: На сайте оракла вроде [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/create-table.html][1]

This chapter describes the syntax for the SQL statements supported by MySQL
сорри, не думал что mySQL теперь тоже оракл

  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/create-table.html

Comment: Странно, а тут вроде нет: [CREATE TABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm). @Barmaley Он стандартный, но не по отношению ко всем объектам базы.

Comment: @javax, вряд ли SQLException можно считать внешним по отношению к базе данных инструментом.

Посмотрите любую книжку по JDBC, там вся работа с базой в try/catch/finally.

Comment: если вы ее создаете из жава кода то перед тем как вызывать создание таблицы сделайте простой селект над ней. прошел = таблица есть. не прошел = нет

Comment: @jmu, это ничего (в многопользовательской среде) не меняет. Сейчас таблицы нет, а через миллисекунду она уже есть.

Comment: 2 @avp: вы и правда думаете что в реальной многопользовательськой системе будет необходимость для многих пользователей вызывать код который создает таблицы по необходимости? сложно представить себе приложение где это оправданно.

Comment: @jmu, а если CREATE_TABLE не выполнится по другой причине ? Exception **все равно** надо обрабатывать. 

Почему не использовать эту обязаловку в логике программы ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от того какие действия необходимо предпринимать если таблица уже есть. Если эти действия лежат в рамках СУБД то смысла и реализовывать клиентским ексепшенном - нет, если же действия должен предпринять клиент или же СУБД используется исключительно как хранилище данных то бизнес логику лучше проверять на клиенте, но я не думаю что это случай оракла - использовать его как просто хранилище - идиотизм.

Но в любом случае чтобы проверить есть ли таблица или нет можно например таким запросом:

```
select count(*) from ALL_TABLES where table_name='table_name'
```

В случае с ораклом наверное правильнее будет написать код на pl/sql который будет отлавливать эксепшен оракла о том что таблица уже есть.

P.S. В оракле действительно нету конструкции "if table not exists", видимо чтобы продвигать объектно ориентированный подход.

P.S.S. хотя если ваш java код является встроенным в СУБД (сам является частью базы) то такой подход правильный.

Comment: @Чад count(*) -- зло! Здесь как раз подошёл бы select с exception. :-)

Comment: А чем зло то?

Comment: Тем, что всю таблицу сканит. count нужен там, где нужен. Ну или в sqlplus.

Comment: IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE Table_name='table') THEN
CREATE TABLE scn_test (value NUMBER) END IF

Comment: @orkaan, в оракле сканит всю таблицу?!?!

@renegator, разве в оракле это есть? "IF NOT EXISTS"

Comment: @Чад, согласитесь в Java реакцию на exeption *в любом случае* надо делать. Тогда зачем нужен select (пусть даже быстрый) и проверка результата (а ведь exception тоже надо обработать)?

Кода больше, выполняется дольше. Просто Вам с проверкой select кажется более логично ?

Comment: @avp, я в своём ответе вроде бы расписал своё отношение к проблеме, и решение через exception я считаю более правильным (если читали внимательно). Мне не понятны голословные высказывания что count это зло и т.д. В моём ответе count используется для проверки существования таблицы.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR Нормально таблицы и многие другие БД объекты постоянны, то есть создаются один раз и больше не удаляются и не пересоздаются, тем более из клиентского кода.

Возможно поэтому *Oracle* пока не спешит реализовать такие фичи как: предикат `IF NOT EXISTS` или статический DDL в PL/SQL. Процитирую [@ConnorMcDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7367293/connor-mcdonald) на [Спроси Тома](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=why-plsql-does-not-support-ddl):

> DDL is a *rare* event in Oracle (unlike some other databases). If you need to run lots of DDL from PL/SQL, I'd be interested in seeing the justification for that.

---

В исключительных случаях, можно создать процедуру, например:

```
create or replace procedure createTableIfNotExists (clauses varchar2) is
    alreadyExists exception;
    pragma exception_init (alreadyExists, -955);
begin
    execute immediate 'create table ' || clauses;
exception when alreadyExists then null;
end createTableIfNotExists;
/
SQL> exec createTableIfNotExists ('testtab (id number, memo varchar (32))') 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> desc testtab

Name Null Type         
---- ---- ------------ 
ID        NUMBER       
MEMO      VARCHAR2(32)
```

Не следует забывать, что вызов DDL произведёт неявный commit текущей транзакции, если таковая имеется.

Comment: я тоже когда то писал что-то подобное - [вот нашёл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/813274/211923) ;-) В Oracle явно не хватает предиката `IF NOT EXISTS` как в MySQL... Или в новых версиях это уже реализовано (я в последнее время не занимаюсь Oracle и не слежу за новыми "фичами")?

Comment: @MaxU Ну да, у меня что-то подобное тоже есть в загашнике, но применений, честно говоря, было немного.

Comment: Позволю себе не согласиться с Томом. У нас например в одной БД более 20-ти приложений, которые работают в разных схемах. На DEV окружении разработчики выполняют DDL по многу раз за день. Все "release deployments" у нас автоматизированы, поэтому такой предикат нам просто необходим. Иначе пришлось бы каждый раз менять скрипты, комментируя ту часть кода, котора успешно выполнилась.

Comment: Я знаю, что существуют надстройки вроде [LiquiBase](https://www.liquibase.org/), позволяющие обойти эту проблему, но у нас свое решение для автоматизации и простой предикат `IF EXISTS` легко решил бы эту проблему на стороне БД.

Answer (score 0):

Это действительно проблема специфичная для Oracle. В Oracle нет предиката `IF NOT EXISTS` позволяющего скажем в MySQL выдать `CREATE TABLE <NAME> IF NOT EXISTS`

Вариантов решения масса, от отлова эксепшна при попытке создания уже существующей таблицы до PL/SQL вставок. 
`SELECT COUNT(*)` действительно не самый лучший способ (я бы сказал даже худший способ)

Обзор различных методов обхода [рассмотрен здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799128/oracle-if-table-exists)

Comment: Да там их всего два - через коунт и ексепшен. Таки почему count то худший вариант?!? Аргументы! Я не говорю что он хорош, через ексепшен на мой взгляд правильнее, но хочется чёткости, а не просто дублирование ответа своими словами.