# Уничтожить последовательность если она существует

Tags: sql, oracle

Перед запуском сценария хочу проверить есть ли в БД секвенция и если есть - дропнуть её. Но DROP SEQUENCE не работает в PLSQL, а IF не работает в SQL. Как быть? Сейчас в начало сценария приписал:

```
DECLARE
    V_TEMP_NUM NUMBER(9) := 0;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_TEMP_NUM FROM USER_SEQUENCES WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = 'TMM_TEMP10_SEQ';
IF V_TEMP_NUM > 0 THEN
  DROP SEQUENCE TMM_TEMP10_SEQ;
END IF;
CREATE SEQUENCE TMM_TEMP10_SEQ
    MINVALUE 0
    START WITH 10
    INCREMENT BY 10
    CACHE 20;
END;
```

Как я и сказал, ругается на DROP.

Comment: `execute immediate 'DROP SEQUENCE TMM_TEMP10_SEQ'` в PLSQL работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Много лет назад я написал небольшую процедуру, которая реализует логику:

```
CREATE/ALTER/DROP <object> IF EXISTS...
```

Можно воспользоваться ей в вашем случае:

```
create or replace procedure admin.re_run_ddl (p_sql in varchar2)
AUTHID CURRENT_USER
as
  l_line        varchar2(500)   default rpad('-',20,'-');
  l_cr          varchar2(2)     default chr(10);
  l_footer      varchar2(500)   default l_cr||rpad('*',20,'*');
  l_ignore_txt  varchar2(200)   default 'IGNORING --> ';
  ORA_00955 EXCEPTION;
  ORA_01430 EXCEPTION;
  ORA_02260 EXCEPTION;
  ORA_01408 EXCEPTION;
  ORA_00942 EXCEPTION;
  ORA_02275 EXCEPTION;
  ORA_01418 EXCEPTION;
  ORA_02443 EXCEPTION;
  ORA_01442 EXCEPTION;
  ORA_01434 EXCEPTION;
  ORA_01543 EXCEPTION;
  ORA_00904 EXCEPTION;
  ORA_02261 EXCEPTION;
  ORA_04043 EXCEPTION;
  ORA_02289 EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_00955, -00955); --ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_01430, -01430); --ORA-01430: column being added already exists in table
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_02260, -02260); --ORA-02260: table can have only one primary key
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_01408, -01408); --ORA-01408: such column list already indexed
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_00942, -00942); --ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_02275, -02275); --ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_01418, -01418); --ORA-01418: specified index does not exist
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_02443, -02443); --ORA-02443: Cannot drop constraint  - nonexistent constraint
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_01442, -01442); --ORA-01442: column to be modified to NOT NULL is already NOT NULL
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_01434, -01434); --ORA-01434: private synonym to be dropped does not exist
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_01543, -01543); --ORA-01543: tablespace '<TBS_NAME>' already exists
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_00904, -00904); --ORA-00904: "%s: invalid identifier"
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_02261, -02261); --ORA-02261: "such unique or primary key already exists in the table"
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_04043, -04043); --ORA-04043: object %s does not exist
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_02289, -02289); --ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
  procedure p(
         p_str      in  varchar2
        ,p_maxlength    in  int     default 120
  )
  is
     i      int := 1;
  begin
    dbms_output.enable( NULL );

    while ( (length(substr(p_str,i,p_maxlength))) = p_maxlength ) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(substr(p_str,i,p_maxlength));
        i := i + p_maxlength;
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line(substr(p_str,i,p_maxlength));
  end p;
begin

  p( 'EXEC:'||l_cr||l_line||l_cr||p_sql||l_cr||l_line );

  execute immediate p_sql;

  p( 'done.' );

exception
  when  ORA_00955 or ORA_01430 or ORA_02260 or ORA_01408 or ORA_00942
        or ORA_02275 or ORA_01418 or ORA_02443 or ORA_01442 or ORA_01434
        or ORA_01543 or ORA_00904 or ORA_02261 or ORA_04043 or ORA_02289
    then p( l_ignore_txt || SQLERRM || l_footer );
  when OTHERS then
    p( SQLERRM );
    p( DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE );
    p( l_footer );
    RAISE;
end;
/
show err
```

Пример использования:

```
prompt clean-up ...
begin
    admin.re_run_ddl('drop sequence BLA_BLA_BLA');
    admin.re_run_ddl('drop procedure BLA_BLA_BLA');
    admin.re_run_ddl('drop table BLA_BLA_BLA');
end;
/
```

Comment: А мне всегда было лень ее писать. Спасибо!

Comment: @Viktorov, рад, что кому-то пригодилось... :)

Comment: Моё мнение: две одинаковые строчки кода не завёрнутые в функцию, два раза в проекте - ошибка дизайна, три раза и более - похоже саботаж.

Comment: @0xdb, если вы про повторы `admin.re_run_ddl()` то это как раз то, для чего создавалась эта процедура - надо было выполнять скрипты с DDL, которые могли содержать ошибки. Если ошибка случалась в середине скрипта, то приходилось после исправления ошибки комментировать все DDL, которые были успешно выполнены до ошибки. Собственно поэтому и название процедуры такое...

Comment: @MaxU Нет конечно, про повторы того, что внутри `admin.re_run_ddl()`.

Comment: @MaxU Я всё правильно понял и мой комментарий  о том же.

Answer (score 0):

А на дроп ругается из за этого (execute immediate), о чём нам напоминает [Коннор на AskTOM](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=why-plsql-does-not-support-ddl):

> DDL - считается редким событием в Oracle (в отличие от других СУБД)

```
DECLARE
    V_TEMP_NUM NUMBER(9) := 0;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_TEMP_NUM FROM USER_SEQUENCES WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = 'TMM_TEMP10_SEQ';
IF V_TEMP_NUM > 0 THEN
  execute immediate 'DROP SEQUENCE TMM_TEMP10_SEQ';
END IF;

 execute immediate '
  CREATE SEQUENCE TMM_TEMP10_SEQ
    MINVALUE 0
    START WITH 10
    INCREMENT BY 10
    CACHE 20';

END;
```

Comment: Собственно это [Коннор](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7367293/connor-mcdonald) так заметил. И также добавил: "Хотелось бы узнать, с какой целью надо выполнять кучу DDL в pl/sql коде". ТС со своей дипломной работой здесь живой пример такой необходимости.

Comment: Да, конечно Коннор. Спасбо, поправил.
По поводу дипломной работы не уловил.