# Распарсить XML с xmltype() с обработкой исключений в запросе

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Есть запрос:

```
select 
    nvl(extractvalue(xmltype(p.src_doc, 871), '//*:' || pd.name), 
        extractvalue(xmltype(p.src_doc, 871), '*/*[local-name()="AdditionalData"][*[local-name()="Name"]="' || pd.name || '"][1]/*[local-name()="Value"]')) as elm_value, 
    pd.guid as param_guid, 
    p.guid as pmnt_guid
  from
    payments p
      join services s
    on p.srv_guid = s.guid
      join parameters_definitions pd
    on s.guid = pd.srv_guid
     left outer join pmnt_elements_values elm
    on p.guid = elm.pmnt_guid and pd.guid = elm.param_guid
 where
    elm.guid is null and p.src_doc is not null;
```

В принципе корректно парсит XML в `clob`, но иногда может возникнуть исключение:

```
ORA-31011: сбой разбора XML
ORA-19202: Возникла ошибка при обработке XML 
LPX-00601: Invalid token in: '//*: PAYMENTTYPE '
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

Проблема в том, что некоторые XML корректны, некоторые нет, таблица довольно объемна. Единого примера XML тоже дать не могу, так как все XML-документы корректны в рамках своей схемы, но по понятным причинам имеют разные значения в нодах, разные неймспейсы и атрибуты в некоторых нодах.

Можно ли как-то обойти/проигнорировать/обработать исключения разбора XML? Можно ли хотя бы как-то получить понимание где конкретно и на чем разваливается парсер?

Версия: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Отловите исключение с `exception when ... then ...` и смотрите, что в конкретном XML документе не так. У вас сложности найти пример, как это сделать?

Comment: Был бы признателен за пример на PL\SQL, но проблема еще в том, что в таблице может быть много таких ситуации и все что выльется через исключение придется смотреть в ручную.

Comment: Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813266/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82/813274#813274) посмотрите, подгоните под ваш случай. Добавте в вопрос, что не получилось.

Comment: @0xdb Спасибо, принцип понятен. Попробую.

Comment: В случае использования процедуры ошибки не ловятся :) Или же я что-то делаю не так) На выходе только успешный текст селекта и успешный 'done') Т.е. выполнение блока exception не происходит. Переписал (вроде бы) правильно.

Comment: Наверное что-то делаете не так. Добавте что получилось прямо в тело вопроса кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/854049/edit).

Comment: Удалось ли Вам устранить ошибку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо обернуть всю логику по разбору XML в функцию, которая обработает исключения и запишет полную информацию об ошибках, например, в таблицу. Как-то так:

```
create table parseErrors (guid raw (16), errm varchar2 (4000), created timestamp);

create or replace function myXmlParser (docGuid raw, doc clob) return varchar2 is
    procedure saveParseError (guid raw, errm varchar2) is 
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
    begin 
        insert into parseErrors values (guid, errm, systimestamp);
        commit;
    end ;
begin
    -- **здесь необходимая логика, в которой может возникнуть ошибка**
    return xmlType (doc).getStringVal (); 
exception when others then 
    saveParseError (docGuid, sqlerrm||chr(10)||sys.dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace());
    return 'errorneous';
end myXmlParser;
/
```

Выборка для теста (вместо sys_guid() должна быть колонка с GUID из запроса):

```
select myXmlParser (sys_guid(), '<row>some data</row>') from dual union all
select myXmlParser (sys_guid(), '</row>illegal XML syntax</row>') from dual
;
```

выведет:

```
RESULT    
------------------------
<row>some data</row>   
errorneous
```

Kакие были ошибки:

```
set lines 999
col errm for a40 wrapp
select * from parseErrors;

GUID                             ERRM                                     CREATED                     
-------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- -----------------------------
7106268B980F02D3E0530A01A8C04FBB ORA-31011: XML parsing failed            2018-07-15 12:32:41,204757000
                                 ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272                                 
                                 ORA-06512: at "DB.MYXMLPARSER", line 10
```

---

PS В вопросе мало информации по локализации причины ошибки, но думаю ссылки на похожие топики [тут](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=ora-31011-on-xmltype-column) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538513/xml-parsing-in-oracle) будут полезны.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! По вашему примеру сделал следующее: https://pastebin.com/TZVg4V7z (надо что бы функция возвращала результат в запросе). Это полностью решило проблему!